# Track Frequency from Microphone using AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, frequency-analysis

Creating an Swift-iOS project that tracks audio frequency from the microphone. Currently using the AudioKit 3.0 framework. I have the following code working in the Xcode simulator but when I run it on a device it doesn't appear to be reading the microphone signal correctly.

```
    // Prepare Microphone
    let mic = AKMicrophone()


    // Connect Microphone to High Pass Filter
    let mixer = AKMixer(mic)
    let highPassFilter = AKHighPassFilter(mic)

    // Set Parameters of Hi Pass filter
    highPassFilter.cutoffFrequency = 7000 // Hz
    highPassFilter.resonance = 0 // dB


    let tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(highPassFilter, minimumFrequency: 7000, maximumFrequency: 8000)
    highPassFilter.play()
    audioKit.audioOutput = tracker
    audioKit.start()

    AKPlaygroundLoop(every: 0.1) {
        let freq = tracker.frequency
        print(freq)
    }
```

Comment: can you clarify "doesn't appear to be reading the microphone signal correctly"

Comment: we see that you answered your own question which is fine, and it may be helpful for others with the same problem. However, as @john_ryan stated, it is unclear what exactly is wrong. I would encourage you to edit the original question and answer so that it is clear what the exact problem was.

Comment: this link may help you: https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/issues/322

Answer (score 4):

I use this code with AudioKit 3 and it works fine:

```
    let mic = AKMicrophone()
    amplitudeTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(mic)
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
    AudioKit.output = amplitudeTracker
    AudioKit.start()
    mic.start()
    amplitudeTracker.start()
```

This is AKAmplitudeTracker but the situation is almost the same with you. Try AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from the dev behind AudioKit. There is a bug in AudioKit 3.0 that's hasn't been fixed in the distribution version. To fix it . Change line 41 of AKManager.swift to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and then create a new Framework to add to your project.

This corrects a problem with the microphone node.